# React.js - error in console when navigating a route

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to implement authentication with the React.js. I am following this [tutorial](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/tree/master/examples/auth-flow)

When I run the example using this tutorial it works great.
When I implement tutorial solution in my project, it works half way. As soon as I go to Login route, it gives me the following error in the console:

> Warning: Failed Context Types: Required context `router` was not specified in  `Login`. Check the render method of `RoutingContext`.

If I refresh the page, then I see I am logged in and it works, just becouse of the error application stops. I am using identical libraries as they do.

This is the code that I use ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/33766/)):

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { browserHistory, Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router'
import auth from './auth'

const App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      loggedIn: auth.loggedIn()
    }
  },

  updateAuth(loggedIn) {
    this.setState({
      loggedIn: loggedIn
    })
  },

  componentWillMount() {
    auth.onChange = this.updateAuth
    auth.login()
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            {this.state.loggedIn ? (
              <Link to="/logout">Log out</Link>
            ) : (
              <Link to="/login">Sign in</Link>
            )}
          </li>
          <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/dashboard">Dashboard</Link> (authenticated)</li>
        </ul>
        {this.props.children || <p>You are {!this.state.loggedIn && 'not'} logged in.</p>}
      </div>
    )
  }
})

const Dashboard = React.createClass({
  render() {
    const token = auth.getToken()

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Dashboard</h1>
        <p>You made it!</p>
        <p>{token}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
})

const Login = React.createClass({

  contextTypes: {
    router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
  },

  getInitialState() {
    return {
      error: false
    }
  },

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()

    const email = this.refs.email.value
    const pass = this.refs.pass.value

    auth.login(email, pass, (loggedIn) => {
      if (!loggedIn)
        return this.setState({ error: true })

      const { location } = this.props

      if (location.state && location.state.nextPathname) {
        this.context.router.replace(location.state.nextPathname)
      } else {
        this.context.router.replace('/')
      }
    })
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label><input ref="email" placeholder="email" defaultValue="vedran" /></label>
        <label><input ref="pass" placeholder="password" /></label> (hint: password1)<br />
        <button type="submit">login</button>
        {this.state.error && (
          <p>Bad login information</p>
        )}
      </form>
    )
  }
})

const About = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return <h1>About</h1>
  }
})

const Logout = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount() {
    auth.logout()
  },

  render() {
    return <p>You are now logged out</p>
  }
})

function requireAuth(nextState, replace) {
  if (!auth.loggedIn()) {
    replace({
      pathname: '/login',
      state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }
    })
  }
}

render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="login" component={Login} />
      <Route path="logout" component={Logout} />
      <Route path="about" component={About} />
      <Route path="dashboard" component={Dashboard} onEnter={requireAuth} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('example'))
```

What am I doing wrong?

It seems this line is producing problems:

```
contextTypes: {
    router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
},
```

Comment: What version of react-router do you have installed? It should be v2.x for the example your using - npm list react-router

Comment: WOW. I copied the entire react folders from the example version. And when I run your command, it shows different routers. Runnign example uses 2.0.0... while my non running example uses 1.0.2. Let me change the version and check it out. Will be back here in no time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an issue with the version of react-router you have installed? The code example in your link is for react-router v2.x

Comment: Great :). It resolved the issue. If I am not mistaken, react  and react-router are 2.0.0 version now? That is most up to date version?